What is the XOR count of AES MixColumn matrix?
I am a beginner and I am learning about XOR counts, (Link to background: https://ia.cr/2014/530).
The 4 by 4 matrix used in the MixColumn operation in AES is [2,3,1,1],[1,2,3,1],[1,1,2,3],[3,1,1,2]. I calculated its XOR count and got it as 152. Is this the correct answer? If not, then please tell me how the XOR count is calculated. Thank you.

I see you asked some specific but arcane questions. Since you've got 20+ rep points, you may talk about your ideas in chat, and we might be able to help you with those questions.

I'm not sure if 152 is correct, but I think the steps are roughly:

determine the XOR count of multiplying with the (binary polynoimal) constants: $1$, $2$, and $3$,

multiply the result from the 1st step by the number of (XOR) sum required for 1 row in MixColumn,

multiply the result from step 2 by the number of rows in the column (which is 4 as we know).


As to determining the XOR count of multiplying a binary polynomial by a constant,

determine the XOR count of multiplying by $x$ (known in maths as indeterminate symbol) - usually this equals the number of non-zero terms in the polynomial.

determine the minimum number of multiplication by $x$ required to reproduce the bit pattern of the constant multiplicand. This is should be the degree of the highest term in the polynomial, as we don't need to add terms higher than this. In the specific case of this Q, this number is same for $2$ and $3$, but a backup of the initial value is required with $3$ (bit pattern 0000_0011), where as $2$ don't (bit pattern 0000_0010).

determine the multiplicative product of non-zero terms in the constant multiplicand and the degree of the reduction polynomial excluding the term with the highest degree (which is $m(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + x^0$. Note $x^0 = 1$ mathematically if you're wondering why this differs from the standard)

take into account bitwise cancellation, and calculate the combined XOR count.


The paper already had a demonstrative example.
As always, if there's something you don't understand, you can ask for clarification in the comments.
You can verify if 152 is the correct number by writing out individual expressions, put them into a calculator (I use command-line Python for its ease of use and versatile programmability)

Hi Danny, you are right ! I referred the paper you mentioned and it says that one row of the AES MixColumn matrix circ(1,1,2,3) requires 38 XOR which means all four rows need 4 * 38 = 152 XOR. Thank you so much !
